# "Unable to resolve module" debuggerWorker errors in recent react-native releases

Tags: react-native

I keep my project(s) relatively up to date with the latest RN releases. This error seems to be coming up more and more lately.

```
Error: Unable to resolve module `./debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.d9da4ed7` from ``:

None of these files exist:
  * debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.d9da4ed7(.native|.native.js|.js|.native.json|.json|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx)
```

Really makes it hard when trying to debug issues and a debugger statement does noting and errors are not reported to the browser tab where the console output goes.

I've already tried wiping `node_modules`. Is this a known issue with a concrete fix available?

Comment: I have fixed with this solutions. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69672343/11752083

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Got stuck with this exact issue for hours. Just found that this occurs only on device where app is already installed with debug mode enabled.

I fixed it by:

- uninstalling manually app from device (cmd+H to display simulator home) then long click on app icon and click on cross to delete app => this forces disabling debug mode,
- then run app again from xcode.

Enabling debug mode after that works normally.

Comment: You solution partially works, When I try to run the application again the problems are gone, however after while this error starts to appear again and I have to cleanup everything again.

It heavily  slows the development. Unfortunately I'm still stuck with this problem :(

Comment: Didn't help for me :(

Comment: I'm stuck here for almost a week. Nothing helped. 

Comment: Didn't help, still doesn't work

Answer (score 4):

I had to come across a similar issue after updating @react-native-community/cli-debugger-ui to 4.2.1. Tried out several methods, nothing worked. Reverting @react-native-community/cli-debugger-ui back to 3.0.0 resolved the issue for me.

Comment: here is the same issue on github https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/1081

Comment: That's the issue I reported on GitHub. Assisting with recreating the issue and coming up with a possible solution.

Comment: This has now been suspected as an issue with React Native ^0.62.0. For more details checkout the link to issue reported to React Native team. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28606

Comment: @AfrarMalakooth  I don't have @react-native-community/cli-debugger-ui in package.json. I understand that you have it there, right?

Comment: @Yossi Yes. I do have it in my yarn.lock file, not package.json.

Comment: Are yiu editing yarn.lock? I thought that we need to leave it to yarn to handle... Adding ia package should be done with package.json...

Comment: @Yossi you're right. Since the error kept on coming I reverted only that change using version control. Try updating @react-native-community/cli-debugger-ui to 4.7.0, I think you might have to manually do that.

Answer (score 0):

I closed the app (pressing home twice and swiping up), then started it again from the simulator and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Happens to me recently using expo and android.
The solution was to clear all Expo Go data:

- Long press the Expo go icon
- Then select App info
- At the bottom of the screen, press Clear Data
- And press Clear all data
- Relaunch expo go and the react native app