# react-native: remote debugger stopped working

Tags: react-native

I always used the debugger with my app and my real device and today out of the blue it stopped working. When switching it on I'm getting this error in my terminal:

```
Error: Unable to resolve module `./debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.cff11639.js` from ``:

None of these files exist:
  * debugger-ui\debuggerWorker.cff11639.js(.native|.native.js|.js|.native.json|.json|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  * debugger-ui\debuggerWorker.cff11639.js\index(.native|.native.js|.js|.native.json|.json|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx)
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (C:\Presto\Frontend 19-5\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:163:15)
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (C:\Presto\Frontend 19-5\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ResolutionRequest.js:52:18)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\Presto\Frontend 19-5\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:287:16)
    at C:\Presto\Frontend 19-5\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:267:42
    at Server.<anonymous> (C:\Presto\Frontend 19-5\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:841:41)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (C:\Presto\Frontend 19-5\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:99:24)
    at _next (C:\Presto\Frontend 19-5\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:119:9)
```

After I switch the deubgger on, the app is just stuck and I cannot press anything. Is there something I can do? I tried

```
gradlew clean
```

And it didn't help. I'm using Android and Windows 10.

Comment: did you tried stop and again start?

Comment: Yes many times, when running gradlew clean you have to stop

Comment: Have a look at the issue https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/1081 Hope it help!!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59658998/expo-unable-to-resolve-module-debugger/60755519#60755519

Comment: I tried all the solutions suggested both on stackoverflow and also on github issue, nothing worked still the exact same problem

Comment: After deleting my cache and reloading chrome it didn't help, I even tried to restart my pc and nothing of course. But then today it started working again without me doing anything. Really strange

Answer (score 0):

I have temporary solution.

**Solution 1**: Just uninstall already installed app which is your using currently.

**Solution 2**: Go to your Settings >> find your app >> Clear data

The reason is The debugging mode is making the issue sometime.

Comment: this is not a solution , how do you debug if you dont enable debugging?

Comment: Your misunderstood, if you updated anything in Gradle, android, and ios folder then try to install it while the old app still exists on your mobile may cause an issue therefore you should uninstall or clear the cache.

Comment: Its definitely working after clearing the data but after i run the react native debugger after pressing 'D' in metro the problem still exists.